# Landserf Bat file does nothing

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am trying to install Landserf on my computer: 
http://www.landserf.org/

When I click on the shortcut, nothing happens, and when I run the bat file it opens and closes immediatly. My boss says that last time they had this problem they simply had to change a parameter in the bat file, but she doesn't know which, and neither do I.

Here are the bat file contents:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\LandSerf
start javaw -Xmx1400m -Djava.library.path=.\lib -classpath    ./jars/landserf230.jar;./jars/jogl.jar;./jars/alloy.jar;./jars/utils230.jar;./jars/RXTXcomm.jar;./jars/gluegen-rt.jar jwo.landserf.LandSerf %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Whenever I run the file the cmd opens and closes immediately. I am not sure what to do, and cannot find anything online to help.

Comment: what happens when you type this into a cmd?

Comment: When troubleshooting a batch file you always execute from the cmd prompt instead of double clicking it with your mouse.

Comment: Program has not been updated since April of 2009.  You may want to just contact the author. email: jwo 'at' soi.city.ac.uk

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, solved by reducing the parameter of allocated memory in the .bat file, as described in the readme file (original documentation in the Landserf installation folder):

> ```
> If you have large amounts of physical memory on your system, you can reallocate more of it
> to LandSerf by editing landserf.sh and changing 1400 in the -Xmx1400m setting to an appropriate
> figure (where 1400m refers to 1400 Mbytes).
> ```

For me, it worked with 500m.